# Trigger Athena saved query via aws athena cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Reading through the [AWS Athena docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/) it is not straightforward to me if it is possible to execute a saved query. Can someone point this out to me as I am just not getting it?

To illustrate my problem further, say I want to programmatically run a batch of queries based on some cron like service.

I would list all of my saved queries ID's via `aws athena list-named-queries`

```
{
  "NamedQueryIds": [
    "kdjois98-dbe0-411f-ad14-jj8dis02MKldQz7h", 
  ]
}
```

Then take these `NamedQueryIds` and run them through a [start-query-execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/start-query-execution.html) and save the results to an S3 bucket.

I am aware that [start-query-execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/start-query-execution.html) allows you to pass in raw SQL, and I will fallback to this as a last resort, but I would prefer to have all of the queries terraformed out and saved for easier debugging/reuse

Answer (score 3):

I think that the only way is to use get-named-query function and then you can insert QueryString from get-named-query to start-query-execution.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found option to run saved queries either and`start-query-execution` documentation is not straight forward. Documentation states the output location is optional but it seemed mandatory when I ran the command  I would agree with @jb, to get the SQL from named-query, store it in a variable and start new query. Here are instruction for start query.

```
aws athena start-query-execution \
    --query-string "SELECT * from MY-TABLE" \
    --work-group "primary" \
    --query-execution-context Database=sampledb,Catalog=AwsDataCatalog \
    --result-configuration "OutputLocation='s3://MY-BUCKET/athenafolder'"
```